# Как убрать дублирующиеся значения из многомерного массива в PHP?

Tags: php, массивы

Как убрать дублирующиеся значения из многомерного массива в PHP?

```
$arr = [
    'a' => [100, 101, 102],
    'b' => [100, 103, 104],
];

// Убираем дублирующиеся значения

// Ожидаемый результат

$arr = [
    'a' => [101, 102],
    'b' => [103, 104],
];
```

Всем спасибо, в итоге, на английском стаке нашёл такое решение, может кому то пригодится:

```
$seen = [];

foreach($arr as &$entry)
{
    $entry  = array_unique(array_diff($entry, $seen));
    $seen   = array_merge($entry, $seen);
}
unset($entry);
```

Правда, результат будет таким, но, мне это даже больше подходит:

```
$arr = [
    'a' => [100, 101, 102],
    'b' => [103, 104],
];
```

Comment: А если `'a' => [100, 101, 100]` - удалять обе сотни? или только одну (какую)? И вообще - дубли внутри одного подмассива - удаляемы? А то, что в результате элементы могут получиться разной размерности - это нормально? А если дублей три значения - удаляются все три, или только два (какие)?

Comment: Вы хотя бы попытались как-то сами решить вашу задачу? Что-то попробовали и у вас не получилось? Вы столкнулись с какой-то трудностью? Или думаете, что кто-то за вас полностью напишет готовый код? ))

Comment: Что и требовалось доказать, Вы не свое время не бережете, не чужое. В первом же комментарии @Akina задавал Вам данные вопросы, а другие люди не зная на них ответы тратили уйму времени.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
    $arr = [
    'a' => [100, 101, 102],
    'b' => [100, 103, 104],
];

$all_items = [];

foreach ($arr as $it) {
    $all_items = array_merge($all_items, $it);
}

$uses = array_count_values($all_items);

$response = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $items) {
    $it = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if($uses[$item] === 1) {
            $it[] = $item;
        }
    }

    $arr[$key] = $it;
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php) - поправьте..второй кусок кода уйдет... и вы очень добрый человек, ведь автор ничего не сделал, чтобы достичь своего желаемого результата

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Прошу прощения, не дочитал ваш комментарий.

Comment: соединить можно без цикла `array_merge(...$arr)`. посчитать повторы и оифильтровать сразу с `array_filter` с `v > 1`. далее сделать `array_map` исходного с `array_diff` вложенного и фильтрованного

Comment: @teran Можете привести рабочий код? Гляньте как Гляньте на результат print_r(['a' => [100, 101, 102], 'b' => [100, 103, 104]]);  array_merge не распаковывает массивы)

Comment: https://ideone.com/94KzT9

Comment: @teran предложил неплохое решение, а у вас Вадим, цикл на цикле и циклом погоняет, логика непрозрачна, вряд ли даже автору будет понятно решение, но +, т.к. оно работает)

Comment: @ЕвгенийТихии Ну конечно, начинающему куда проще будет понять функциональщину чем обычный рекурсивный подход. Автор в алгоритмах плутается а вы тут все "прелести" php показываете

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Функциональщину? Ты используешь 3 цикла и 2 функции, еще и бессмысленным перекладыванием занимаешься. У меня же единственный цикл по исходному массиву с 2 функциями. Садись, два тебе, даже в код не вник.

Я уже просто даже не говорю о бесполезно созданном массиве, который ты не используешь `$response = [];`, просто код лапша.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант предлагаю решение...)

---

```
/* Исходный массив */
$rawArr = [
    'a' => [100, 101, 102, 105, 106],
    'b' => [100, 103, 104, 106, 105],
];

/* Записываем пересечения в новый $interArr массив */ 
$interArr = array_intersect ($rawArr['a'], $rawArr['b']);

/* Формируем новый массив в цикле */
foreach ($rawArr as $indexRaw => $valueRaw) {
    $diffArr[$indexRaw] = array_diff ($rawArr[$indexRaw], $interArr);
}

/* Массив без дублей */
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($diffArr);
```

---

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [1] => 101
            [2] => 102
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [1] => 103
            [2] => 104
        )

)
```